# Static CSS & JS files 404 on Magento CE 2.4.3 on nginx

Tags: nginx, magento2

I've got an issue with CSS not being loaded on Magento CE 2.4.3 on both frontend or backend (but the HTML is being rendered correctly).  I am in dev mode.  The site is compiled and cache is disabled.  In order to simplify things I've also disabled the CSS version directory mapping using:

```
INSERT INTO core_config_data (path, value) VALUES ('dev/static/sign', 0)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value = 0;
```

And cleared cache.  (This is the equivalent of Stores > Config > Developer > Static File Settings: Sign Static Files = No, but I can't use the admin UI at present).

I'm getting 404s on the CSS & JS files - as seen in the nginx logs:

```
80.229.148.211 - - [24/Mar/2022:22:15:21 +0000] "GET /frontend/a1/hawthorn/en_GB/css/print.css HTTP/1.1" 499 0 "https://m243.mydomain.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:98.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/98.0" "-"
80.229.148.211 - - [24/Mar/2022:22:15:48 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 10342 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:98.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/98.0" "-"
80.229.148.211 - - [24/Mar/2022:22:16:07 +0000] "GET /frontend/a1/hawthorn/en_GB/mage/calendar.css HTTP/1.1" 404 9424 "https://m243.mydomain.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:98.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/98.0" "-"
80.229.148.211 - - [24/Mar/2022:22:16:16 +0000] "GET /frontend/a1/hawthorn/en_GB/mage/requirejs/mixins.js HTTP/1.1" 404 9449 "https://m243.mydomain.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:98.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/98.0" "-"
80.229.148.211 - - [24/Mar/2022:22:16:18 +0000] "GET /frontend/a1/hawthorn/en_GB/requirejs-config.js HTTP/1.1" 404 9434 "https://m243.mydomain.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:98.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/98.0" "-"
80.229.148.211 - - [24/Mar/2022:22:16:21 +0000] "GET /frontend/a1/hawthorn/en_GB/css/styles-l.css HTTP/1.1" 404 9421 "https://m243.mydomain.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:98.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/98.0" "-"
80.229.148.211 - - [24/Mar/2022:22:16:22 +0000] "GET /frontend/a1/hawthorn/en_GB/requirejs/require.js HTTP/1.1" 404 9425 "https://m243.mydomain.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:98.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/98.0" "-"
80.229.148.211 - - [24/Mar/2022:22:16:25 +0000] "GET /frontend/a1/hawthorn/en_GB/css/styles-m.css HTTP/1.1" 404 9420 "https://m243.mydomain.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:98.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/98.0" "-"
80.229.148.211 - - [24/Mar/2022:22:16:25 +0000] "GET /pub/media/content/banner_inks.gif HTTP/1.1" 200 12146 "https://m243.mydomain.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:98.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/98.0" "-"
80.229.148.211 - - [24/Mar/2022:22:16:25 +0000] "GET /pub/media/content/banner_roller.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 31981 "https://m243.mydomain.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:98.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/98.0" "-"
80.229.148.211 - - [24/Mar/2022:22:16:54 +0000] "GET /frontend/a1/hawthorn/en_GB/mage/requirejs/mixins.js HTTP/1.1" 404 9450 "https://m243.mydomain.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:98.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/98.0" "-"
80.229.148.211 - - [24/Mar/2022:22:16:57 +0000] "GET /frontend/a1/hawthorn/en_GB/images/logo_white_black_on_clear_crop.svg HTTP/1.1" 404 9422 "https://m243.mydomain.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:98.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/98.0" "-"
80.229.148.211 - - [24/Mar/2022:22:16:59 +0000] "GET /frontend/a1/hawthorn/en_GB/css/print.css HTTP/1.1" 404 9421 "https://m243.mydomain.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:98.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/98.0" "-"
80.229.148.211 - - [24/Mar/2022:22:17:19 +0000] "GET /frontend/a1/hawthorn/en_GB/requirejs-config.js HTTP/1.1" 404 9434 "https://m243.mydomain.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:98.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/98.0" "-"
80.229.148.211 - - [24/Mar/2022:22:17:38 +0000] "GET /favicon/stores/1/favicon.png HTTP/1.1" 404 9389 "https://m243.mydomain.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:98.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/98.0" "-"
```

Even though I know I shouldn't need to in dev mode I force deployed the static content (since it wasn't showing up in pub/static) with:

```
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_GB --exclude-theme Magento/luma --exclude-theme Magento/blank -f
```

And I can see the files then written in their respective directories e.g. (from the magento home dir)

```
$ ls -al pub/static/frontend/a1/hawthorn/en_GB/css/
total 612
drwxrwxr-x  2 magento nginx    127 Mar 24 21:26 .
drwxrwxr-x 96 magento nginx   4096 Mar 24 21:26 ..
-rw-rw-r--  1 magento nginx  18371 Mar 24 21:26 email.css
-rw-rw-r--  1 magento nginx   4965 Mar 24 21:25 email-fonts.css
-rw-rw-r--  1 magento nginx  14797 Mar 24 21:26 email-inline.css
-rw-rw-r--  1 magento nginx   5465 Mar 24 21:25 print.css
-rw-rw-r--  1 magento nginx 124412 Mar 24 21:25 styles-l.css
-rw-rw-r--  1 magento nginx 437701 Mar 24 21:26 styles-m.css
```

I've ensured all permissions are readable by the web server group (nginx) and ownership set running this from the magento root dir:

```
sudo chown -R magento:nginx ./
```

This is my nginx.conf:

```
# For more information on configuration, see:
#   * Official English Documentation: http://nginx.org/en/docs/
#   * Official Russian Documentation: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/

user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/doc/nginx/README.dynamic.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    client_max_body_size 200M;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    # For multiple (Magento2) php-fpm sites
    upstream fastcgi_backend {
        server  unix:/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
    }

    server {
        listen       80 default_server;
        listen       [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name  _;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
        client_max_body_size 200M;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        location / {
            client_max_body_size 200M;
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;
            location = /40x.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
        }
    }


    include sites-enabled/*.conf;
    server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;

}

This is my vhost:

server {

    server_name mydomain.com www.mydomain.com m243.mydomain.com;

    #index index.html;
    #root /var/www/test;

    set $MAGE_ROOT /var/www/hpm;
    include /var/www/hpm/nginx.conf.sample;

    #location ^/le_connector/connector.php {
    #    allow all;
    #    satisfy any;
    #}

    # Load configuration files for the default server block.
    #include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;


    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/m243.mydomain.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/m243.mydomain.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
    if ($host = www.mydomain.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = mydomain.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = m243.mydomain.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot



    listen 80;

    server_name mydomain.com www.mydomain.com m243.mydomain.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot

}
```

This is my nginx.conf.sample

```
root $MAGE_ROOT/pub;

index index.php;
autoindex off;
charset UTF-8;
error_page 404 403 = /errors/404.php;
#add_header "X-UA-Compatible" "IE=Edge";

# Deny access to sensitive files
location /.user.ini {
    deny all;
}

# PHP entry point for setup application
location ~* ^/setup($|/) {
    root $MAGE_ROOT;
    location ~ ^/setup/index.php {
        fastcgi_pass   fastcgi_backend;

        fastcgi_param  PHP_FLAG  "session.auto_start=off \n suhosin.session.cryptua=off";
        fastcgi_param  PHP_VALUE "memory_limit=756M \n max_execution_time=600";
        fastcgi_read_timeout 600s;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout 600s;

        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ ^/setup/(?!pub/). {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~ ^/setup/pub/ {
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    }
}

# PHP entry point for update application
location ~* ^/update($|/) {
    root $MAGE_ROOT;

    location ~ ^/update/index.php {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(/update/index.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass   fastcgi_backend;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO        $fastcgi_path_info;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

    # Deny everything but index.php
    location ~ ^/update/(?!pub/). {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~ ^/update/pub/ {
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    }
}

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}

location /pub/ {
    location ~ ^/pub/media/(downloadable|customer|import|custom_options|theme_customization/.*\.xml) {
        deny all;
    }
    alias $MAGE_ROOT/pub/;
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
}

location /static/ {
    # Uncomment the following line in production mode
    # expires max;

    # Remove signature of the static files that is used to overcome the browser cache
    location ~ ^/static/version\d*/ {
        rewrite ^/static/version\d*/(.*)$ /static/$1 last;
    }

    location ~* \.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg|svgz|webp|avif|avifs|js|css|eot|ttf|otf|woff|woff2|html|json|webmanifest)$ {
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        expires +1y;

        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$2 last;
        }
    }
    location ~* \.(zip|gz|gzip|bz2|csv|xml)$ {
        add_header Cache-Control "no-store";
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        expires    off;

        if (!-f $request_filename) {
           rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$2 last;
        }
    }
    if (!-f $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$2 last;
    }
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
}

location /media/ {

## The following section allows to offload image resizing from Magento instance to the Nginx.
## Catalog image URL format should be set accordingly.
## See https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/configuration/general/web.html#url-options
#   location ~* ^/media/catalog/.* {
#
#       # Replace placeholders and uncomment the line below to serve product images from public S3
#       # See examples of S3 authentication at https://github.com/anomalizer/ngx_aws_auth
#       # resolver 8.8.8.8;
#       # proxy_pass https://<bucket-name>.<region-name>.amazonaws.com;
#
#       set $width "-";
#       set $height "-";
#       if ($arg_width != '') {
#           set $width $arg_width;
#       }
#       if ($arg_height != '') {
#           set $height $arg_height;
#       }
#       image_filter resize $width $height;
#       image_filter_jpeg_quality 90;
#   }

    try_files $uri $uri/ /get.php$is_args$args;

    location ~ ^/media/theme_customization/.*\.xml {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~* \.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg|svgz|webp|avif|avifs|js|css|eot|ttf|otf|woff|woff2)$ {
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        expires +1y;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /get.php$is_args$args;
    }
    location ~* \.(zip|gz|gzip|bz2|csv|xml)$ {
        add_header Cache-Control "no-store";
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        expires    off;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /get.php$is_args$args;
    }
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
}

location /media/customer/ {
    deny all;
}

location /media/downloadable/ {
    deny all;
}

location /media/import/ {
    deny all;
}

location /media/custom_options/ {
    deny all;
}

location /errors/ {
    location ~* \.xml$ {
        deny all;
    }
}

# PHP entry point for le_connector application
location /le_connector {
    root $MAGE_ROOT;
    location ~ ^/le_connector/connector.php {

        ### This fixes the problem:
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
        ################################

        fastcgi_pass   fastcgi_backend;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ ^/le_connector/(?!pub/). {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~ ^/le_connector/pub/ {
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";#    
    }
} 

# PHP entry point for main application
location ~ ^/(index|info|connector|get|static|errors/report|errors/404|errors/503|health_check)\.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass   fastcgi_backend;
    fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;

    fastcgi_param  PHP_FLAG  "session.auto_start=off \n suhosin.session.cryptua=off";
    fastcgi_param  PHP_VALUE "memory_limit=756M \n max_execution_time=18000";
    fastcgi_read_timeout 600s;
    fastcgi_connect_timeout 600s;

    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

    #pass multi-site variables
    fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_TYPE $MAGE_RUN_TYPE;
    fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_CODE $MAGE_RUN_CODE;

    include        fastcgi_params;
}

gzip on;
gzip_disable "msie6";

gzip_comp_level 6;
gzip_min_length 1100;
gzip_buffers 16 8k;
gzip_proxied any;
gzip_types
    text/plain
    text/css
    text/js
    text/xml
    text/javascript
    application/javascript
    application/x-javascript
    application/json
    application/xml
    application/xml+rss
    image/svg+xml;
gzip_vary on;

# Banned locations (only reached if the earlier PHP entry point regexes don't match)
location ~* (\.php$|\.phtml$|\.htaccess$|\.git) {
    deny all;
}
```

Any ideas would be really appreciated - thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0):

So it turned out in my flailing around to fix other issues I'd set these values mistakenly:

```
MariaDB [magento]> select * from core_config_data where value like "%_base_url%" \G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
 config_id: 71
     scope: default
  scope_id: 0
      path: web/unsecure/base_static_url
     value: {{unsecure_base_url}}
updated_at: 2022-03-23 22:12:52
*************************** 2. row ***************************
 config_id: 72
     scope: default
  scope_id: 0
      path: web/unsecure/base_media_url
     value: {{unsecure_base_url}}
updated_at: 2022-03-23 22:12:52
*************************** 3. row ***************************
 config_id: 73
     scope: default
  scope_id: 0
      path: web/secure/base_static_url
     value: {{unsecure_base_url}}
updated_at: 2022-03-23 22:12:52
*************************** 4. row ***************************
 config_id: 74
     scope: default
  scope_id: 0
      path: web/secure/base_media_url
     value: {{unsecure_base_url}}
updated_at: 2022-03-23 22:12:52
*************************** 5. row ***************************
 config_id: 701
     scope: default
  scope_id: 0
      path: web/unsecure/base_link_url
     value: {{unsecure_base_url}}
updated_at: 2022-03-23 22:12:52
*************************** 6. row ***************************
 config_id: 703
     scope: default
  scope_id: 0
      path: web/secure/base_link_url
     value: {{unsecure_base_url}}
updated_at: 2022-03-23 22:12:52
6 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```

Clearing these with

```
update core_config_data set value = NULL where value like "%_base_url%";
```

sorted out the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

```
upstream fastcgi_backend {
    server   unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
 }
 server {
    listen 80;
    server_name _;
    set $MAGE_ROOT /var/www/html/magento;

root $MAGE_ROOT/pub;

index index.php;
autoindex off;
charset UTF-8;
error_page 404 403 = /errors/404.php;
#add_header "X-UA-Compatible" "IE=Edge";
client_max_body_size 32M;

# Deny access to sensitive files
location /.user.ini {
    deny all;
}

# PHP entry point for setup application
location ~* ^/setup($|/) {
    root $MAGE_ROOT;
    location ~ ^/setup/index.php {
        fastcgi_pass   fastcgi_backend;

        fastcgi_param  PHP_FLAG  "session.auto_start=off \n suhosin.session.cryptua=off";
        fastcgi_param  PHP_VALUE "memory_limit=756M \n max_execution_time=600";
        fastcgi_read_timeout 600s;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout 600s;

        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ ^/setup/(?!pub/). {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~ ^/setup/pub/ {
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    }
}

# PHP entry point for update application
location ~* ^/update($|/) {
    root $MAGE_ROOT;

    location ~ ^/update/index.php {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(/update/index.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass   fastcgi_backend;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO        $fastcgi_path_info;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

    # Deny everything but index.php
    location ~ ^/update/(?!pub/). {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~ ^/update/pub/ {
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    }
}

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}

location /pub/ {
    location ~ ^/pub/media/(downloadable|customer|import|custom_options|theme_customization/.*\.xml) {
        deny all;
    }
    alias $MAGE_ROOT/pub/;
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
}

location /static/ {
    # Uncomment the following line in production mode
    # expires max;

    # Remove signature of the static files that is used to overcome the browser cache
    location ~ ^/static/version\d*/ {
        rewrite ^/static/version\d*/(.*)$ /static/$1 last;
    }

    location ~* \.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg|svgz|webp|avif|avifs|js|css|eot|ttf|otf|woff|woff2|html|json|webmanifest)$ {
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        expires +1y;

        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$2 last;
        }
    }
    location ~* \.(zip|gz|gzip|bz2|csv|xml)$ {
        add_header Cache-Control "no-store";
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        expires    off;

        if (!-f $request_filename) {
           rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$2 last;
        }
    }
    if (!-f $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$2 last;
    }
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
}

rewrite /media/catalog/product/cache/[a-z0-9]+/(\S+) /media/catalog/product/$1 last;
location /media/ {

    location ~* \.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg|js|css|swf|eot|ttf|otf|woff|woff2)$ {
        # Proxying to AWS S3 storage.
        resolver 8.8.8.8;
        set $bucket "mermaidtools-magento-files-2023020510381437940000000b";
        proxy_pass https://s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/$bucket$uri;
        proxy_pass_request_body off;
        proxy_pass_request_headers off;
        proxy_intercept_errors on;
        proxy_hide_header "x-amz-id-2";
        proxy_hide_header "x-amz-request-id";
        proxy_hide_header "x-amz-storage-class";
        proxy_hide_header "Set-Cookie";
        proxy_ignore_headers "Set-Cookie";
    }

    try_files $uri $uri/ /get.php$is_args$args;

    location ~ ^/media/theme_customization/.*\.xml {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~* \.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg|svgz|webp|avif|avifs|js|css|eot|ttf|otf|woff|woff2)$ {
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        expires +1y;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /get.php$is_args$args;
    }
    location ~* \.(zip|gz|gzip|bz2|csv|xml)$ {
        add_header Cache-Control "no-store";
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        expires    off;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /get.php$is_args$args;
    }
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
}

location /media/customer/ {
    deny all;
}

location /media/downloadable/ {
    deny all;
}

location /media/import/ {
    deny all;
}

location /media/custom_options/ {
    deny all;
}

location /errors/ {
    location ~* \.xml$ {
        deny all;
    }
}

# PHP entry point for main application
location ~ ^/(index|get|static|errors/report|errors/404|errors/503|health_check|pinfo)\.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass   fastcgi_backend;
    fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;

    fastcgi_param  PHP_FLAG  "session.auto_start=off \n suhosin.session.cryptua=off";
    fastcgi_param  PHP_VALUE "memory_limit=756M \n max_execution_time=18000";

    fastcgi_param  HTTPS "on";
    fastcgi_param  HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO "https";

    fastcgi_read_timeout 600s;
    fastcgi_connect_timeout 600s;

    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;
}

gzip on;
gzip_disable "msie6";

gzip_comp_level 6;
gzip_min_length 1100;
gzip_buffers 16 8k;
gzip_proxied any;
gzip_types
    text/plain
    text/css
    text/js
    text/xml
    text/javascript
    application/javascript
    application/x-javascript
    application/json
    application/xml
    application/xml+rss
    image/svg+xml;
gzip_vary on;

# Banned locations (only reached if the earlier PHP entry point regexes don't match)
location ~* (\.php$|\.phtml$|\.htaccess$|\.git) {
    deny all;
}

}
```

Comment: Could you explain what all those code does?

Comment: that configuration to mange the Magento website in nginx server